# Jasmine complains about imported css in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to run some unit tests on a javascript module I wrote.

The test is simple:

```
import {FornaContainer} from '../app/scripts/fornac.js';

describe('A forna container', function() {
    it('should accept a colorscheme', function() {


    });
});
```

The problem is that in `../app/scripts/fornac.js` I import a css file:

```
import '../styles/fornac.css';
```

This causes jasmine to produce the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
SyntaxError: /home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/app/styles/fornac.css: Unexpected token (1:4)
> 1 | svg {
    |     ^
  2 |   display: block;
  3 |   min-width: 100%;
  4 |   width: 100%;
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2907:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2894:38)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2264:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1955:17)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2294:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1823:8)
    at Parser.parse (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1396:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:45:50)
    at File.parse (/home/mescalin/pkerp/projects/fornac/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:480:24)
```

Removing the `import ../styles/fornac.css` line in `fornac.js` removes the error.

Any ideas for how to test my javascript file without getting errors about the css import?

**Edit**

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: {fornac: './scripts/fornac.js',
      rnaplot: ['./scripts/rnaplot.js'],
      rnatreemap: './scripts/rnatreemap.js'},
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: '[name]'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css'
      }
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Importing css is not ES6. What is it? Custom JS flavors?

Comment: It's [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) called through webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to prefix your file import with the loader, `css`, according to the [css-loader docs](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#usage):

```
import 'css!../styles/fornac.css';
```

Comment: could you also post your `webpack.config.js`? That would help dissect the issue

Comment: I just added it to the post